# How to lock Laravel project after a certain period of time?

Tags: laravel-5

I have done a good final year project and I want to sell it out after presentation, my worry is lecturers use our projects for their personal benefits when we give them out for marking. Somebody told me about locking a project after a certain period of time but I have no idea, some advice how I can get this done?.

Comment: what do you mean with "locking"?

Comment: I mean something that will render someone unable to use the the app after sometime like setting a password  automatically or any possible mean.